# How can I mock a Ruby "require" statement in RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, thor

I have a Ruby cli program that can optionally load a user-specified file via `require`.  I would like to unit test this functionality via RSpec.  The obvious thing to do is to mock the require and verify that it happened.  Something like this:

```
context 'with the --require option' do
  let(:file) { "test_require.rb" }
  let(:args) { ["--require", "#{file}"] }
  it "loads the specified file"
    expect(...something...).to receive(:require).with(file).and_return(true)
    command.start(args)
  end
end
```

(That's just typed, not copy/pasted - the actual code would obscure the question.)

No matter what I try, I can't capture the `require`, even though it's occurring (it raises a `LoadError`, so I can see that).  I've tried a variety of things, including the most obvious:

```
expect(Kernel).to receive(:require).with(file).and_return(true)
```

or even:

```
let(:kernel_class) { class_double('Kernel') }
kernel_class.as_stubbed_const
allow(Kernel).to receive(:require).and_call_original
allow(Kernel).to receive(:require).with(file).and_return(true)
```

but nothing seems to hook onto the `require`

Suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So `require` is defined by `Kernel` but `Kernel` is included in `Object` so when you call `require` inside this context it is not necessarily the `Kernel` module that is processing the statement.

**Update**

I am not sure if this exactly solves your issue but it does not suffer from the strange behavior exhibited below:

```
file = 'non-existent-file'
allow(self).to receive(:require).with(file).and_return(true)
expect(self).to receive(:require).with(file)
expect(require file).to eq(true)
```

[Working Example](https://repl.it/@engineersmnky/Stub-Require)

**OLD Answer:**

**This is incorrect and exists only for posterity due to the up-votes received. Some how works without the `allow`. Would love it if someone could explain why as I assumed it should raise instead. I believe the issue to be related to `and_return` where this is not part of the expectation. My guess is we are only testing that self received `require`, `with_file`, and that the `and_return` portion is just a message transmission (thus my updated answer)**

You can still stub this like so:

```
file = 'non-existent-file.rb'
allow_any_instance_of(Kernel).to receive(:require).with(file).and_return(true)
expect(self).to receive(:require).with(file).and_return(true)
require file
```

Since I am unclear on your exact implementation since you have obfuscated it for the question I cannot solve your exact issue.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I needed.  The combination of `allow_any_instance_of(Kernel)` and `expect(self)` would never have occurred to me.

Comment: Thanks to @engineersmnky and the [RSpec issue they opened](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/1278), I got this working. The final answer was simple: `allow_any_instance_of(subject_class).to receive(:require); expect_any_instance_of(subject_class).to receive(:require).with(file_name).and_return(true); expect { subject }.to output(expected_output).to_stdout` Without limiting the allow/expect_any_instance_of to the class being tested, it caught all sorts of other requires, but this worked perfectly. Thanks!